# How can I look for specific instances of an id using jQuery when a page uses the id multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to collect information from a page (http://kvrx.org) about the song, artist, and album it's playing at any given time. I'm trying to load it using jQuery, but the issue here is that the page I'm trying to load uses the same ID multiple times, so I end up getting the same text twice. How can I look for specific instances of an id using jQuery?

HTML

```
<p>
    <span id='song'></span><br />
    <span id='artist'></span><br />
    <i><span id='album'></span></i><br />
    <span id='albumart'></span>
</p>
```

JavaScript

```
function updateTags() {
    $("#song").load("http:/kvrx.org #track-name");
    $("#artist").load("http:/kvrx.org #artist-name");
    $("#album").load("http:/kvrx.org #album-name");
    $("#albumart").load("http:/kvrx.org #album-artwork");
}
```

Result (I only want one of each of these lines to show up)

```
The Black Angels - Empire
Song: The Black Angels - Empire

Various Artists - KVRX
Artist: Various Artists - KVRX

Local Live, Vol. 10: Untitled
Album: Local Live, Vol. 10: Untitled
```

Comment: Specific in what way? If they have the same ID, what will be your criteria to determine the one you want?

Comment: @squint - They always reflect the same info, so it really doesn't matter for the purpose of this application. Ideally the former one, I suppose!

Comment: jQuery has methods for targeting various elements in the resulting collection by index or position. Have you checked [jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com) yet?

Comment: Ya. Don't worry about the id. You can iterate those spans with by index.

Comment: @JesseFarmer - I'm attempting to use both the .index() and the .eq() methods by changing my code to `$("#song").load("http:/kvrx.org #track-name").index(0);`, but it's not changing anything - any tips?

Comment: If `$("#song")` returns multiple elements, then `.load()` is going to operate on that whole collection of elements. If you only want to operate on one, then pick which one you want before you start working with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have no idea if this will work or not but you could try:

```
$("#song").load("http:/kvrx.org #track-name:eq(0)");
```

Otherwise you will have more control using `$.get()` and only need to make one request instead of 4

```
$.get('"http:/kvrx.org', function(html){
   var $song = $(html).find('[id="track-name"]').eq(0);
   $("#song").html($song);
})
```

Comment: The former suggestion worked - I wasn't using eq() right at all! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Last one will be more efficient though since don't have to request same page 4 times...although could use `$.ajaxSetup` to cache requests to that url